# what do you call a vise with a slot in it for a saw?

Tags: tools

[image]

This vise has a slot so you can saw the thing you’re clamping.  What do you call this kind of vise?

Comment: Let me get my magnifying glass....

Comment: Terrible picture to get a useful answer. Some picture-framing vises have such a feature, but given that the tiny picture does not even **show** the slot or slots, I can't tell if this is one of those or not.

Comment: if you're handy with a computer you can zoom in on the picture.  this is the only one i have access to because i don't know what to google.

Comment: Looks to be just a table mount "clamp on" vise.

Comment: look on the left side on the inside

Comment: That picture is of a small "bench vise", but I've never seen a "slot for a saw".  Sorry, might have to wait until you find a better image.